# Slicing dataframe by comparing all values of one column to all values of column of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I have  a question regarding slicing dataframes.
I have two dataframes: halo_field with indexes 3447, 4024...

```
           H_masa  N_subs      ...                 H_z             rh
3447  1.066437e+11       1      ...        88419.632812  160354.430049
4024  4.423280e+11       1      ...        49013.289062   65239.433084
4958  3.171903e+11       1      ...        23239.701172   48248.401956
5749  2.817211e+11       1      ...        46585.765625   65032.216212
6512  2.471275e+11       1      ...        93403.398438  123058.838527
```

and I have dataframe subhalo with one of the columns named 'halo_index' indexing into the dataframe halo from which the halo_field is the slice (thus we have such halo_field indexes) - this is printout of subhalo.halo_index (on the right):

```
0                0
1                0
2                0
3                0
4                0
            ...   
4366516    7713551
4366517    7713552
4366518    7713553
```

I would like to slice subhalo dataframe into the dataframe subhalo_field so that it only contains rows with halo_index column value which is also contained in the halo_field.index. Problem is that of course those two columns are not the same length and I can't do it like this (comparing row to row vs. comparing all values of one column to all values of another):

```
subhalo_field=subhalo[subhalo.halo_index==halo_field.index].copy()
```

I get this error:

```
File "group_sh.py", line 139, in <module>
subhalo_field=subhalo[subhalo.halo_index==halo_field.index].copy()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/ops.py", line 1223, in wrapper
raise ValueError('Lengths must match to compare')
ValueError: Lengths must match to compare
```

How can I slice my subhalo dataframe so I can compare subhalo.halo_index to halo_field.index and copy just those subhalos into subhalo_fields that have maching halo_index and halo_field.index?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, a `merge` on the index of `halo_field` and the `halo_index` column of `subhalo` might be what you're looking for (this defaults to inner-join behaviour):

```
halo_field.merge(subhalo, left_index=True, right_index=False, right_on='halo_index')
```

Comment: Tried it, but from the length of the subhalo dataframe I see that is not what I need. I need to compare halo_field.index and subhalo.halo_index and copy to subhalo_field dataframe just those subhalos from the subhalo dataframe in which halo_index value matches some value from halo_field.index. For instance  I can have value of halo_field.index 3440, then I want to compare that value with values of subhalo.halo_index, say five of my subhaloes have subhalo.halo_index=3440, then copy those five subhalos to dataframe subhalo_field. I would like to do that for every value of halo_field.index.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
subhalo_field=subhalo[subhalo.halo_index.isin(halo_field.index)].copy()
```